# Change all generated user/{uid} paths to user/{uuid} and process them without the redirect

Tags: path-aliases, 10

I need to change all generated user/{uid} paths to user/{uuid} and process them without the redirect. The tricky part is that I need to:

- Output canonical URLs to user/{uuid} instead of user/{uid}
- Process them correctly without redirections and custom controllers

How can I achieve this?

Comment: This probably isn’t worth the effort, it sounds like the standard “security through obscurity” that people who know tend to advise against. Have you considered that the user ID is probably going to be in countless other places too? CSS classes, data attributes in the HTML, and so on? It would be infinitely wiser IMO to spend this development time on pen-testing and securing the app in more robust ways

Comment: I agree with your point of view from the technical perspective, however, this one is coming from the management point of view. So it's all about 'I am the user number 296', not that someone is going to hack something. I suggested to increase the initial counters, so we start from 1M ID and there will be no user with ID 296, but at this moment they cant accept the fact that the user knows his number.

Comment: Tell them they can have what they want, but that it’s a non-standard, unrecommended action to take, and will therefore take ~3 months to implement and test. In my experience that tends to make non-tech management change their tune pretty quickly :)

Comment: In seriousness though, I doubt you'll find an easy solution to this, there are just so many things you'll have to check and change (for example the node author autocomplete, which shows user ID in brackets). And that's just core, who knows what fun awaits in contrib and custom land

Comment: Why should they be worried about users who know their IDs? I am asking because this seems a question about what they think is a solution for their problem. Knowing the underlying problem would help to give a better answer.

Comment: Given that the user ID is not considered sensitive date, in Drupal, there are many places where the user ID appears, including as CSS class on the user profile page. As @Clive said, there are many things that should be changed.

Comment: You could use Pathauto? Other than that this effort is pretty futile.

Comment: I would remove the automatic generation of paths for the user, delete all generated paths for user/{uid}, alter the canonical user route to user/{uuid} and load the user object with the EntityUuidConverter param converter or a custom one. However, pages such as user/1/edit can still be called, which is why the adjustment would be necessary here as well.